# Is MAX_PATH enough to hold the path from GetSystemDirectory()?

Tags: windows, winapi, directory, system

From my understanding, that path will be a single-letter (the driver), followed by `"\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32`" so that `MAX_PATH` is more than enough to hold that path filled by [GetSystemDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemdirectoryw). So it's safe to do:

```
TCHAR dir[MAX_PATH] = {0};
if(GetSystemDirectory(dir, sizeof(dir) / sizeof(*dir)) == 0) {
  // check for GetLastError()
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: `<drive>:\Windows` is the *default* installation folder, but users are free to choose whatever path they want to install Windows into. So the path may be longer

Comment: The safest way is to use SHGetKnownFolderPath which will allocate the path for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation provided for the recommended alternative to `GetSystemDirectory` ([which is `ShGetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw)) says the following about its `pszPath` parameter:

> A pointer to a null-terminated string of length MAX_PATH which will
> receive the path. If an error occurs or S_FALSE is returned, this
> string will be empty. The returned path does not include a trailing
> backslash. For example, "C:\Users" is returned rather than
> "C:\Users\".

So, yes, `MAX_PATH` will be a big enough buffer size.